# In OSX Mountain Lion, what is the planned replacement for portmap?

Tags: macos, rpc, osx-mountain-lion

(I'd be very sorry to hear this is a stupid question, but I've done already some considerable googling and can't make a sense out of it.)

If I try to develop some software that uses RPC, I do not only find out that the RPC Portmapper is not yet running on my system, but also I can't find nor start it. While I could not find any trace about this, this is a clear sign for me that Apple decided to either withdraw support for the good only ONC RPC, or they switched to something else, that I cannot find tho.

https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/rutgers/notes/rpc/step3.html (they don't seem to be all that outdated) still notes that is just has to be done with `launchctl start com.apple.portmap` but that one clearly does not exist for me anymore: `launchctl start error: No such process`

I can only confirm that portmap is not available with 10.8 (Mountain Lion) anymore while I could verify it is still existing on 10.6 (Snow Leopard). I don't know what's the state in 10.7 (Lion).

(It's amazing how at the beginning I thought of Stackoverflow as a very clever thing, yet, everytime I ask a question, it starts with apologies and me admitting my stupidity)

Comment: Apologies around your question don't help. Losing more time reading apologies isn't a solution for losing time on trivial/stupid question. If you have a question, let's just hope it's not stupid (doesn't seem stupid to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

turns out my question was at least half stupid. I still can't find any documentation on this, but `launchctl start rpcbind` seems to float my boat. And that is the more BSD variant of doing it.

Let's hope this is at least helpful to somebody else in some documentation way. And thanks for being my teddy bear.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW on the page you linked to, where it lists the command for OS X as `launchctl start com.apple.portmap` it also lists the command for BSD as `/usr/sbin/rpcbind`, which is there in Mtn Lion and would probably explain why `launchctl start rpcbind` works.